# Determine if entity type is fieldable

Tags: 8, entities

Given an $entityTypeId as string, how can I determine if this entity type is fieldable? That is, if entities of that type implement FieldableEntityInterface?

Comment: Next question here, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243736/get-field-definitions-across-bundles-including-base-fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a simpler way but I think this should be pretty reliable:

```
// Inject the entity_type.manager service instead if possible.
$class = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getDefinition($entity_type_id)
    ->getOriginalClass();

$interface = 'Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface';

if (in_array($interface, class_implements($class))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice! Maybe `is_a($class, $interface, TRUE)` would be faster than `in_array()`?

Comment: @donquixote Forgot that function even existed! Yeah it'd almost definitely be a bit faster to use `is_a`. Probably nothing earth shattering though

Comment: And even easier is to use the predefined method entityClassImplements() on the entity_type definition object, ->getDefinition()->entityClassImplements(FieldableEntityInterface::class)

Comment: I would clarify first what _fieldable_ stands for. In Drupal 7 terminology entity type becomes fieldable if it has "_fieldable_" key in its definition. Which means it accepts fields being attached to it. From this point the answer is not correct because in Drupal 8 **all** content entities implement _FieldableEntityInterface_ but not all of them are truly fieldable. You can check for _field_ui_ route to find out if it is possible to attach fields to a given entity type `$entity_type_definition->get('field_ui_base_route')`.

Comment: @Berdir Unrelated observation: I found that entityClassImplements() uses is_subclass_of(), not is_a(). See https://3v4l.org/ovN2g. This means that $definition->entityClassImplements(Node::class) will return false for node entity type. This is not a problem in this case because we are calling it with FieldableEntityInterface::class, and no entity type has this as the entity class.

Comment: @ya.teck In my case I am happy with any entity that implements FieldableEntityInterface. But the distinction is worth mentioning.

Comment: @ya.teck it is quite correct, actually. That flag no longer exists. any content entity consists of fields. To be extra correct, you could check whether the storage implements https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21DynamicallyFieldableEntityStorageInterface.php/interface/DynamicallyFieldableEntityStorageInterface/8.3.x, but all content entities using the standard storage do. The field_ui flag key, as the name implies, only defines if and where field_ui should expose the UI. But even without UI, configurable fields will work as long as the storage implements it

Comment: @donquixote yeah, that is an interesting thing to be aware of but very unlikely to be used that way, if you'd want to check for that, you could use getClass() or getOriginalClass() and just compare against that.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit simpler:

```
if (method_exists(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition($entity_type_id)->getOriginalClass(), 'hasField')) {
...
}
```